# loading bing maps page into Chromium browser (in Delphi)

Tags: bing-maps, chromium

This code creates an HTML page that loads bing maps for a specific address (passed by the program), and then it loads that page into a Chromium browser. I've tested the HTML file that this produces and if I double-click the file, my default browser opens and the page loads correctly. However, when I try to load this page into a Chromium browser window within the program (which has worked in the past for other pages) only the header shows up (material from *div id="TitleDiv"*) but the map never shows. I'm trying to figure out why the HTML isn't loading when programmatically loaded into the browser when it loads correctly when manually loaded.

I've tried this with and without the *ChromWebPage.Browser.Reload;* line.

This is my exact Delphi code except that I've omitted our Bing maps key here. (Easiest way to get text to file with Delphi that I know if is with a TStringList which is why the code is formatted like this.)

```
  mMap := TStringList.Create;
  with mMap do begin
    Add('<!DOCTYPE html> ' );
    Add('<html> ' );
    Add('<head>');
    Add('<title>' + sCaption + '</title> ');
    Add('    <meta charset="utf-8" /> ');
    Add('    <script type="text/javascript"> ');
    Add('    var map, searchManager; ');
    Add('    function GetMap() { ');
    Add('        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map("#myMap", { ');
    Add('            credentials: "KEY-HERE" ');
    Add('        }); ');
    //Make a request to geocode passed address
    Add('        geocodeQuery("' + sAddress + '"); ');
    Add('    } ');
    Add('    function geocodeQuery(query) { ');
    //If search manager is not defined, load the search module.
    Add('        if (!searchManager) { ');
    // Create an instance of the search manager and call the geocodeQuery function again.
    Add('            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Search", function () { ');
    Add('                searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map); ');
    Add('                geocodeQuery(query); ');
    Add('            }); ');
    Add('        } else { ');
    Add('            var searchRequest = { ');
    Add('                where: query, ');
    Add('                callback: function (r) { ');
    // Add the first result to the map and zoom into it.
    Add('                    if (r && r.results && r.results.length > 0) { ');
    Add('                        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(r.results[0].location); ');
    Add('                        map.entities.push(pin); ');
    Add('                        map.setView({ bounds: r.results[0].bestView }); ');
    Add('                    } ');
    Add('                }, ');
    Add('                errorCallback: function (e) { ');
    // If there is an error, alert the user about it.
    Add('                    alert("No results found."); ');
    Add('                } ');
    Add('            }; ');
    //Make the geocode request.
    Add('            searchManager.geocode(searchRequest); ');
    Add('        } ');
    Add('    } ');
    Add('    </script> ');
    Add('    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BingMapsCredentials.js"></script> ');
    Add('    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap" async defer></script> ');
    Add('</head> ');
    Add('<body style="width:100%;height:100%"> ');
    Add('    <div id="TitleDiv" style="padding-bottom: 15px; ');
    Add('                             padding-top: 5px; ');
    Add('                             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; ');
    Add('                             font-size:   14px; ');
    Add('                              font-weight: bold; ');
    Add('                             position:relative;">' + sCaption + '</div> ');
    Add('    <div id="myMap" style="width:100vw;height:95vh;position:relative;"></div> ');
    Add('</body> ');
    Add('</html> ');
    sTempFile := GetLocalAppDir + 'mymap.html';
    if fileExists(sTempFile) then DeleteFile(sTempFile);
    savetofile(sTempFile);
    mMap.free;
  end;
  ChromWebPage.DefaultUrl := sTempFile;
  ChromWebPage.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(sTempFile);
  ChromWebPage.Browser.Reload;
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to latest version of DCEF3 resolved the issue. Suspecting that the scripts were incompatible with the older DCEF3.